# ternary operator is not working as expected instead throws an error

Tags: php

```php
<?php echo date("d")===1? "st": (date("d")===2? "nd" :(date("d")===3? "rd":"th")):"th";  ?>
```

Here's what i would want `if day===1` then print out `st` otherwise `if date===2` it should print `nd` otherwise if `date===3` print out `rd` otherwise print out  the default `th`

here is the error emitted

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ';'
```

Comment: It won't handle output 21 as 21st, use a switch statement or use intl module for getting ordinal value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I totally forgot about `date` format `S`:

```
echo date("DS");
```

Answer (score 1):

A parsing error occurs when the language syntax rules are broken. Your code does not compile, therefore it is not executed. The error is produced by the fragment `:"th"` that follows the last closed parenthesis. Remove it and the code will compile.

However, it will not work correctly because you use `===` to compare a string (returned by [`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)) against a number (`1`, `2` or `3`). Such a comparison never succeeds because `===` compares both the types of the operands and their values.

Read about the PHP [comparison operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) `==` and `===`.

There are also logical errors in your code. `date('d')` returns the current day of month. On the 21<sup>st</sup>, 22<sup>nd</sup>, 23<sup>rd</sup> and 31<sup>st</sup> of the month the code uses an incorrect suffix.

A better approach, with is also easier to read, is to use a `switch` statement like this:

```php
$day = date('d');
switch ($day) {
  case '01':
  case '21':
  case '31:
    $suffix = 'st';
    break;
  case '02':
  case '22':
    $suffix = 'nd';
    break;
  case '03:
  case '23':
    $suffix = 'rd';
    break;
  default:
    $suffix = 'th';
    break;
}
echo("${day}${suffix}");
```

Or you can work smarter, not harder, and use the `j` and `S` format specifiers of `date` and let PHP do the heavy lifting:

```php
echo(date('jS'));
```

Check it [online](https://3v4l.org/NIM10).

---

[`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date) and the other [date & time functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php) are old and out of fashion since about 10 years ago. I recommend you to use the [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class and [its friends](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php). They are easier to use to do date & time computations and they can handle timezones (the old functions cannot).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?php echo date("d")===1 ? 
    "st" : 
    (
        date("d")===2 ?
            "nd" :
            (
                date("d")===3?
                "rd":"th"
            )
    ); // You had here :"th"; ?>
```

The :"th" at the end (see the comment in the code) breaks the ternary
operator syntax.